# "AGE" meaning in the term AGE-associated autoantibodies?

Tags: autoimmune-disease, antibodies

What is the "AGE" in AGE-associated autoantibodies? Please describe it if you can.

---

It was mentioned in the book "The End of Alzheimer's: The First Programme to Prevent and Reverse the Cognitive Decline of Dementia" by Dr Dale Bredesen ([link](https://books.google.de/books?id=O5EODgAAQBAJ&pg=PT228&lpg=PT228&dq=%22For%20example,%20instead%20of%20a%20twentieth-century%20diagnosis%20of%20subjective%20cognitive%20impairment,%20the%20twenty-first-century%20diagnosis%20may%20be%20subjective%20cognitive%20impairment%20of%20types%201.5%20(70%20percent)%20and%203%20(30%20percent),%20due%20to%20grade%203%20central%20insulin%20resistance,%20AGE-associated%20autoantibodyies,%20and%20innate%20immune%20system%20activation%20due%20to%20_Aspergillus_%20and%20HLA-DR/DQ%2012-3-52B%20interaction,%20with%20associated%20gliotoxin%20production.%22&source=bl&ots=_06I_0BrXl&sig=cdPo2UmjQBq4LN6seWsnTb616p0&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiem5CFjZbZAhXBAewKHcHIB3MQ6AEIMDAA#v=onepage&q=%22For%20example%2C%20instead%20of%20a%20twentieth-century%20diagnosis%20of%20subjective%20cognitive%20impairment%2C%20the%20twenty-first-century%20diagnosis%20may%20be%20subjective%20cognitive%20impairment%20of%20types%201.5%20(70%20percent)%20and%203%20(30%20percent)%2C%20due%20to%20grade%203%20central%20insulin%20resistance%2C%20AGE-associated%20autoantibodyies%2C%20and%20innate%20immune%20system%20activation%20due%20to%20_Aspergillus_%20and%20HLA-DR%2FDQ%2012-3-52B%20interaction%2C%20with%20associated%20gliotoxin%20production.%22&f=false) to the relevant page on google.books, screenshot below).

Here is the full sentence:

> For example, instead of a twentieth-century diagnosis of subjective cognitive impairment, the twenty-first-century diagnosis may be subjective cognitive impairment of types 1.5 (70 percent) and 3 (30 percent), due to grade 3 central insulin resistance, AGE-associated autoantibodies, and innate immune system activation due to *Aspergillus*  and HLA-DR/DQ 12-3-52B interaction, with associated gliotoxin production.

[image]

Comment: A member for over a year with admirable rep on Stack Overflow... You've already got a good answer to your question, but I wonder - what did the Google (or any other search engine) show when you tried to research this?

Comment: Instead of an uncredited screenshot a proper reference for your source an/or readable text might also be appreciated.

Comment: See @LangLangC's comment. I think you need to cite the source of the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Advanced Glycation End-products

These are basically proteins and lipids that are glycated in a high glucose environment, *e.g.*  in untreated diabetic patients. Wikipedia has an article about the details.

In case you need more details than Wikipedia provides: you can find numerous peer reviewed articles via [Pubmed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=%22Glycation%20End%20Products,%20Advanced%22[nm]), [this one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12616989) for example was suggested by user [Lucky](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/613/lucky).

Comment: I like that the answer is concise and to the point. Perhaps, to keep in line with the site policies on references, something like this abstract can be added: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12616989. It illustrates the example of diabetic patients that you gave.

Comment: I believe we are revisiting the need for references for things which are obvious